# unable to add a text field in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am developing a game using cocos2d framework. I want to add a text field to enter player's name. I used UITextField and the textfield is visible and the keyboard gets pop up. But my problem is the Return key is not working. I tried out many times but all in vain. please help me out, or is there any other way to add a text field in cocos2d. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you implement all needed delegate methods for your text field. For example,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

method.

Comment: thanks for your reply..i implemented that method..but its not working. my code is -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;}   i print in a log also..but cant get it print. Can i implement this method for cocos2d also?

Comment: what do you mean "cant get it print"?

Comment: where do you trying to print smth? if in one of your UITextFieldDelegate methods and it is not printing anything to console, place a breakpoint there and check if your delegate method is called when you press return button.

Comment: hey i got my ans...@interface MenuLayer : CCLayerColor<UITextFieldDelegate>  i didn't add <UITextFieldDelegate> in my menulayer. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

did you use resignfirstresponder ? for returning keyboard just add the code as

[textfield resignFirstResponder];

also add this line of code on place where you want to return the keyboard such as on cctouchbegin or on click of any button. Hope this will work.